# How can i use conditionals in list comprehension?

Tags: haskell, if-statement, list-comprehension

I am trying to build a list of 0's using list comprehension.  But i also want to make an index 1 where i choose in the list.  For example myList 5 2 = [0,1,0,0,0] where 5 is the number of elements and 2 is the index.

```
myList el index = [0 | n <- [1..el], if n == index then 1 else 0]
```

but this results in an error.

Comment: Can you explain what `0` is doing in the head of your list comprehension?

Comment: If not with list comprehensions, you may also do by a monadic way like `[1..el] >>= return . bool 0 1 . (index ==)`

Answer (score 4):

The smallest change that fixes that is

```
myList el index = [if n == index then 1 else 0 | n <- [1..el]]
```

Note that what's at the *left* of `|` is what generates the list elements. A list comprehension of the form `[ 0 | ...]` will only generate zeros, and the `...` part only decides how long is the resulting list.

Further, in your code the compiler complains because at the *right* of `|` we allow only generators (e.g. `n <- someList`), conditions (e.g. `x > 23`), or new definitions (`let y = ...`). In your code the `if ...` is interpreted to be a condition, and for that it should evaluate to a boolean, but `then 1` makes the result a number, triggering a type error.

Another solution could be

```
myList el index = replicate (index-1) 0 ++ [1] ++ replicate (el-index) 0
```

where `replicate m 0` generates a list with `m` zeros, and `++` concatenates.

Finally, note that your `index` is 1-based. In many programming languages, that's unconventional, since 0-based indexing is more frequently used.

Comment: that's interesting, i never thought about looking at it that way.  Thanks!

Comment: the [*smallest*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) change would probably be `[x | n <- [1..el], x<-[if n == index then 1 else 0]]`. :)

Comment: @WillNess Touché!